# Convert Pandas DataFrame to a list suited for django templates

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

How would you convert the `pd.DataFrame` obtained after group by `field1` and `field2`

```
                          field3 \
field1  field2                            
240502  000361            value1
        005936            value2
        006984            value3

                          field4 
field1  field2                            
240502  000361           valuef1
        005936           valuef2
        006984           valuef3
```

to JSON

```
[{
    "field4": "valuef1",
    "field3": "value1"
}, {
    "field4": "valuef2",
    "field3": "value2"
}, {
    "field4": "valuef3",
    "field3": "value3"
}]
```

and then to

```
[{
    u'field4': u'valuef1',
    u'field3': u'value1'
}, {
    u'field4': u'valuef2',
    u'field3': u'value2'
}, {
    u'field4': u'valuef3',
    u'field3': u'value3'
}]
```

I've come up with

```
json.loads(stats.to_json(orient='records'))
```

But it seems too much. I need to consume it in the django templates.

```
  {% for s in stats %}
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #c5dbec;color:#3d3d3d;background-color:#ffffff" align="center">{{ s.field3 }}</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #c5dbec;color:#3d3d3d;background-color:#ffffff" align="right">{{ s.field4 }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
               field3   field4
field1 field2
240502 361     value1  valuef1
       5936    value2  valuef2
       6984    value3  valuef3

In [57]: df.to_dict('r')
Out[57]:
[{'field3': 'value1', 'field4': 'valuef1'},
 {'field3': 'value2', 'field4': 'valuef2'},
 {'field3': 'value3', 'field4': 'valuef3'}]
```

Comment: not exactly, it seems to maintain the index fields `(field1, field2)` in the result dictionary, which is nice, but I need to strip them like if you would do the `group by` in SQL and reading from queryset.